How to create dynamic workflows in Kogito?
I have a unique scenario where the end user can define/edit certain flows(bpmn). Is there any way in Kogito that I can achieve this? I want to create new and also edit the bpmn after deployment. It also needs to be updated to my repository.
PS: I know that workflows need to be static and yet I need to do this. is there any way?
I tried to expose the contents of the bpmn so that I can edit that in the bpmn editor built in my application. But I had no luck in exposing the contents of the bpmn file.
